# Export 3D model from blender to .cad

Tags: export, import

I need to export my models to .cad format.
But Blender has only one exporter for AutoCAD, but the file format is .dxf.

My only idea is to download AutoCAD so i can import my model into it and export to .cad. But im not sure if this is even possible.

Is there another way to export my model to .cad?

Comment: Welcome Edward :) `.dxf` is Autodesk's official **interchange** format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD_DXF and should work fine. Anyway, enjoy blender.se!

Comment: Thank you @poor :) But i have to send the 3D Models to a company, and they say they only accept `.cad` Format.
Someone on cadtutor.com said ".cad is not common and created by a program that's no longer exist... ". So maybe i have to search for a better company..

Comment: Mmh. Not an expert in cad, but I think converting isn't an option, since you can't double check the file for correctness afterwards. Might be helpful: http://www.file-extension.org/en/extensions/cad

Comment: It seems that even Autocad cannot open .cad files (QuickCAD format, owned by... Autodesk!) see https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-open-QuickCAD-cad-files-in-AutoCAD.html the suggestion is to use AutoSketch  to convert it to dxf...

Comment: I already have the models as `.dxf`, but the company needs `.cad`

Comment: So, your only chance could be to use QuickCAD...

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking the same. But im afraid that i can't import my models to QuickCAD, so i have to create them again in this software.